change value of input type range... dont work same change with mouse
I have 13 inputs type range. The initial value are 0
I can change the values with the mouse for example.... how i can do to change its parameters but with javascript for example, because if i change the values using id and val() and .change() the values changes... but dont wotk the funtions if i do it with mouse...
<input type="range" min="-13" max="13" class="rechancices" id="qwe1253">
<input type="range" min="-13" max="13" class="rechancices" id="qwe1254">
<input type="range" min="-13" max="13" class="rechancices" id="qwe1255">
<input type="range" min="-13" max="13" class="rechancices" id="qwe1256">
<input type="range" min="-13" max="13" class="rechancices" id="qwe1257">


$("#qwe1251").val(13).change()

.. change the value, but dont work any event... bit if u click in imput it work
solution with javascrit to change inputs range values and dont mix DOM anda jQuery

What exactly are you trying to do? Set the value or listen for a change event? You seem to be talking about both as if they are the same thing. A [mre] may help us understand the problem.

@Barmar  and  how la the function to do it by DOM?

document.getElementById("qwe1251").value = 13;

@Barmar it change the value of input... but i nerd that it do the same that do if i change the value with the Mouse....

@xear I was just addressing a comment that was saying that you should have written $("#qwe1251").value = 13;. The vanilla JS equivalent of calling .change() is more complicated and won't fit in a comment.

your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/dqfxm7vr/3/

If you want to change properties you can use HTMLElement.setAttribute, for example document.getElementById("qwe1251").setAttribute('min', -14)
